# AngularJS - Button next in multiple step form submit directly in first step

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, forms

I've created a dynamic multiple step form (With ng-show) but I have this issue : 
When I put the button next outside of form, the user can navigate in step without filling the form.
And when I put the button into every DIV (therefore in the form), the button next submit all of form (but blank) in my data base ...
If you have a suggest for me, I take it with pleasure !

This is my HTML :

```
<form ng-submit="submitEvent(event)">

<div ng-show="data.step == 1">
  <div style="border-bottom:none !important; background : transparent; text-align:center;">
  <i class="fa fa-edit fa-4x" id="iconstep-ajust"></i>
  <h4 class="text stable" style="font-size: 25px; position: relative; top: 50px;  font-family: lobster;">Post</h4>
  </div>
  <img id="separation-step" src="img/line.png"></img>
  <div class="list" style="top:80px;">
  <label class="item item-input item-floating-label" style="border:none;">   
    <input type="text" style="color:#FFF;font-size: 22px;text-align:center;" placeholder="Post name" ng-model="event.nameid">
  </label>
  <label class="item item-input item-floating-label" style="border:none;">
    <textarea style="color:#FFF;font-size: 14px;text-align:center;background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);" placeholder="Description de l'événement" ng-model="event.descriptionid"></textarea>
  </label>
</div>
</div>

<div ng-show="data.step == 2">
  <div style="border-bottom:none !important; background : transparent; text-align:center;">
  <i class="fa fa-clock-o fa-4x" id="iconstep-ajust"></i>
  <h4 class="text stable" style="font-size: 25px; position: relative; top: 50px;  font-family: lobster;">hour</h4>
  </div>
  <img id="separation-step" src="img/line.png"></img>
  <div class="list" style="top:80px;">
  <label class="item item-input item-floating-label" style="border:none;">
    <input type="date" style="color:#FFF;font-size: 22px;text-align:center;" placeholder="EEE - MMM - yyyy" ng-model-options="{timezone: 'UTC'}" ng-model="event.dateid" placeholder="Date">
  </label>
  <label class="item item-input item-floating-label" style="border:none;">
    <input type="time" style="color:#FFF;font-size: 22px;text-align:center;" placeholder="HH:mm:ss" ng-model-options="{timezone: 'UTC'}" ng-model="event.hourid" placeholder="Heure">
  </label>
</div>
</div>

<div ng-show="data.step == 3">
  <div style="border-bottom:none !important; background : transparent; text-align:center;">
  <i class="fa fa-users fa-4x" id="iconstep-ajust"></i>
  <h4 class="text stable" style="font-size: 25px; position: relative; top: 50px;  font-family: lobster;">Users</h4>
  </div>
  <img id="separation-step" src="img/line.png"></img>
  <div class="list" style="top:80px;">
  <label class="item item-input item-floating-label" style="border:none;">
    <input type="number" style="color:#FFF;font-size: 18px;text-align:center;" placeholder="Users" ng-model="usersid">
  </label>
  <label class="item item-input item-floating-label" style="border:none;">
    <input type="number" style="color:#FFF;font-size: 16px;text-align:center;" placeholder="Age" ng-model="event.ageid">
  </label>
</div>
</div>

<div ng-show="data.step == 4">
  <div style="border-bottom:none !important; background : transparent; text-align:center;">
  <i class="fa fa-map-marker fa-4x" id="iconstep-ajust"></i>
  <h4 class="text stable" style="font-size: 25px; position: relative; top: 50px;  font-family: lobster;">Localisation</h4>
  </div>
  <img id="separation-step" src="img/line.png"></img>
  <div class="list" style="top:80px;">
  <label class="item item-input item-floating-label" style="border:none;">
    <input type="text" style="color:#FFF;font-size: 18px;text-align:center;" ng-model="event.addressid" placeholder="Adresse (Sans le n° de rue)">
  </label>
  <label class="item item-input item-floating-label" style="border:none;">
    <input type="text" style="color:#FFF;font-size: 22px;text-align:center;" placeholder="Ville" ng-model="event.townid">
  </label>
</div>
<button class="button button-icon icon ion-checkmark-round" style="position: absolute; top: 2px; right: 5px; color:#FFF; z-index:1000;" type="submit" value="Add Event" ng-click="stepsuccess()"></button>
</div>

</form>
<button class="button button-icon icon ion-ios-arrow-forward" style="position: absolute; top: 2px; right: 5px; color:#FFF; z-index:1000;" ng-hide="data.step == 4" ng-click="nextStep()"></button>



</ion-content>
```

My controller JS :

```
  $scope.nextStep = function() {
    $scope.data.step += 1;
  }

  $scope.data = {
    step: 1,
  }
```

Thanks for your time !

Comment: Add type="button" to the button if it is inside the form. Or use <input type="button" ... >

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue a while back. I was using ng-disabled on the button until form is valid: `ng-disabled="formName.$invalid"`. The submit effect is because HTML5 spec says that the default behaviour of a button in a form should be submit. You can use this directive to prevent this behaviour.

```
app.directive('preventDefault', function () {
    return {
        link: function (scope, element, attributes) {
            element.click(function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                event.stopPropagation();
            });
        }
    };
});
```

As @Mindastic pointed out, adding an attribute `type="button"` on your button also solves the problem without the necessity of a runtime compile by angular. :)

Comment: This is OK, but this adds unnecessary complexity to the code during runtime. It should be enough with changing the input type or adding type="button" to the button.

Comment: That works as well. Personally I didn't notice any performance issues when trying to log it. So, either way works fine. You just add `prevent-default` as a attribute and life becomes simpler. :)

Comment: @Mindastic Edited accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

You can disable the the button until all form elements you need are completed and valid, using the `ng-disabled` directive, for example:

```
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" ng-disabled="artistSignupForm.$invalid" ng-click="send()">{{t 'artist-signup.submitBtn'}}</button>
```

In my case, I am using angular's native form validation checker `$invalid` (which you should use, if you want to), but can bind the `ng-disabled` directive to any other validation expression you require.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But if I use ng-disabled in next button, I can't go in step two because he is disabled. And is not user friendly to put ng-disabled at the end of form, because the user must return to first step for fill the form.
I want user can't go in second step if first step is not filled ..
Thanks

Comment: Agree, using `ng-disabled` directive is preferable to repeating the button in every step of the form. I would write a function and assign it to ng-disabled that checks the current step's form inputs and returns true when that step is complete.

Comment: @YngDev31, you don't have to disable the button for the entire form. You can add a validator to the directive that is a function which returns true/false based on the inputs currently shown and interacted with by the user. So you can indeed use the ng-disabled directive to control the flow within your multi-step form, as long as your validation function is smart enough to detect the step the user is at. This should not be a hard thing to do.